# Was Lt. Cmdr. Nella Daren intentionally Crusher-like?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, behind-the-scenes

In "Lessons", Picard falls in love with a new head of Stellar Sciences, [Lt. Cmdr. Nella Daren](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nella_Daren).

I'm going to suggest that she really looks a lot like Dr. Crusher (long red hair, similar age, etc.) and even (IMO) sounds like her.   ([Here's](https://www.reddit.com/r/TNG/comments/mcqp0z/commander_daren_looks_just_like_dr_crusher/) is a Reddit thread which proves it's not only me.)

[image]

Question:   Was this intentional casting and acting?  Are we to believe that it's a case of:

- Intentional similarity that would be perceived as a reason for Crusher to be jealous, or
- In universe we are supposed to believe that Picard "has a type" or consciously or unconsciously is attracted to her due to her similarity to Crusher, or
- Out of universe, casting was influenced by similarly to Crusher when imagining who would be a credible love interest for Picard

Comment: I think any similarity in physical traits is entirely incidental, perhaps a casting choice to support the notion of romantic rivalry between Darren and Crusher, but Picard's "type" has nothing to do with physical traits... Darren showed considerable passion for her work and that more than anything else attracted his interest.

Comment: @AnthonyX: I guess Vash showed passion for her work too, in her own way.

Comment: I don't see the similarity.  But finding anyone else on the planet that did would help your case that the entire question isn't a false premise.  There's archived Usenet posts from 1990s and trekkie forums to use google-fu on.

Comment: I see the resemblance, for the record.

Comment: Look, of course she isn't the same person, but IMO if they has needed to recast Crusher for some reason, this Wendy Hughes would have been the most perfect actor I could have expected to find.

Comment: @lucasbachmann:   [Here you go](https://www.reddit.com/r/TNG/comments/mcqp0z/commander_daren_looks_just_like_dr_crusher/)

Comment: For some reason I opened this question with thoughts of "Why would you want another Wesley?!?!?"

Comment: Since, as TNG went on (spoiler alert!), Picard & Crusher are increasingly shown to have a romantic interest in each other, the physical resemblance between Daren and Crusher seem to be a likely reason for Picard's interest in Daren. All of the attraction, none of the awkward history.

Comment: @FreeMan:  And no bangs!  (/fringe)